# Using @IBSegueAction with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, ibsegueaction

Thanks to **AD Progress's** excellent research and answer below, I finally figured out what's going on with `IBSegueAction`s.

If you hook up a `rootViewController` segue (or any other kind, presumably) to an `IBSegueAction` in its `UINavigationContoller`, but it doesn't find it there, it will look at the next view controller up the responder chain, until it finds an `IBSegueAction` with the correct signature. If it doesn't find one, it'll call `init(with coder: NSCoder)` on the `rootViewController`. If only that was documented somewhere…

---

**Notes**

***Note**: This is a minimal example to illustrate the problem - how to pass parameters when initialising a view controller contained in a modal `UINavigationController` using an `IBSegueAction`. I'm aware that this isn't how you would normally present a detail view.*

***Note 2**: I know how to use segues with `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue)`. What I want to know how is how to pass non-optional parameters when initialising a view controller contained in a modal `UINavigationController` using an `IBSegueAction`*

***Note 3**:  I know how to use use an `IBSegueAction` to a view controller not contained in a `UINavigationController` (e.g. pushing on the nav stack)*

---

**Original Question**

I have the following setup…

[image]

A list of people in a `UITableViewController`. Tapping on a `PersonCell` presents a `PersonViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`

To avoid having an optional `Person` in the `PersonViewController`, I'm trying to use `IBSegueAction`s.

My first thought was that I need one for the segue between the `PeopleViewController` and the `PersonNavController`, and the segue between the `PersonNavController` and the `PersonViewController` as follows…

```
class PeopleViewController: UITableViewController {

    // Table view delegate methods here

    @IBSegueAction func showPerson(_ coder: NSCoder, sender: Any?) -> PersonNavController? {
        guard let cell = sender as? PersonCell else { return nil }
        return PersonNavController(coder: coder, person: cell.person)
    }
}
```

---

```
class PersonNavController: UINavigationController {

    private let person: Person

    required init?(coder: NSCoder, person: Person) {
        self.person = person
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @IBSegueAction func root(_ coder: NSCoder) -> PersonViewController? {
        return PersonViewController(coder: coder, person: person)
    }
}
```

---

```
class PersonViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var name: UILabel!

    private let person: Person

    required init?(coder: NSCoder, person: Person) {
        self.person = person
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        name.text = person.firstName
    }
}
```

The problem here, it turns out, is that even though you can hook up a segue action to the segue between a `UINavigationController` and its `rootViewController`, it doesn't get fired as, in the example above, the `super.init(coder: coder)` in `PersonNavController` calls  `PersonViewController.init(coder: NSCoder)` (which isn't implemented).

Any thoughts as to how I can get this working?

Comment: i've never seen something done like this. i'd say this is the wrong way to do it. dont' pass values to the navigation controller like that, in the tableview controller, when you present the viewcontroller in the navigation controller, you should customize the PersonViewController init methods to include the person your'e passing, then initiliaze a Uinavigaqtion controller, set PersonViewController root of the navigation controller, then do a self.navigationController presentViewController:UINavigationController which will have the root of the PersonViewController and then it works perfectly

Comment: That’s fine if you’re not using storyboards… but in this case I am

Comment: yeah, i get that, and in that regard, idk what to do since i've never used storyboards, programatic code is much much easier to customize in scenarios that require advanced transitioning with various nested controllers in navigationcontrolelrs, custom nav, and tabbars. sorry i can't be of more help :(

Comment: don't have to be flexible when the world needs programatic code, and that's what''s in demand once you get past the interview phase, what's not in demand is 4chan meme features likes like storyboarding and swift UI. just saying, save yourself the heachache, learn to loadView and you'll never look back.

Comment: I guess you have nothing to add to this conversation?

Comment: use interface builder as much as you wish, but at the end of the day, guess what? you're still gonna have to code views programmatically, just like you can learn swift all you want, but guess what? you're still gonna have to know Obj-C. accept it, it won't hurt and it's alleviating to rid yourself of the marketing team's brainwashing that at apple, it's really just drag and drop and bang, you made Twitter 2.0

Comment: Like @Loxx, I don't use Storyboards. But what catches my eye is the use of *two* navigation controllers. Since each have their own VC stack (push/pop), how does this work? `People` really should segue (push) to `Person`. (1) Check for optionals in `prepareForSegue`. (2) If you absolutely need to have a second UINavigationController, make it a child view controller to something the first one segues too.

Comment: @dfd Don't worry about the actual content in the question - this was just a minimal example to illustrate the problem. The modal nav controller could contain a settings view controller for example (which is a pretty common use case), or anything else. But again, don't worry about why I'm doing it… what I'm actually trying to get at is how to use `IBSegueAction`s with modal `UINavigationController`s - this is a new feature in iOS 13 that allows you to instantiate "storyboard" view controllers with additional parameters in their `init` methods

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To achieve the result which you want I recreated a simple project which I will link on my GitHub.

To start off, you need to get rid of the segue you have created to your Navigation controller and recreate it.

[image: Recreate the Segue]

Next select present Modally and name your segue with an identifier

[image: Present modally]

[image: Segue Identifier]

Next you need to define the IBSegueAction in your first ViewController

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    let persons = ["Robert", "Peter", "Dave"]
    var selectedPerson = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @IBSegueAction
    private func showPerson(coder: NSCoder, sender: Any?, segueIdentifier: String?)
        -> PersonViewController? {
        return PersonViewController(coder: coder, personDetails: persons[selectedPerson])
    }
    
    
    //MARK:- TableView Methods
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return persons.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "personCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = persons[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedPerson = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowPerson", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Then add the implementation of `init?(coder: NSCoder, personDetails: String)` in the PersonViewController as follows.
Xcode will yell that you need to implement `required init?(coder: NSCoder)`
Just tap fix.

PersonViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class PersonViewController: UIViewController {
    //Your data passed in below as non optional constant
    let personDetails: String
    
    //The received data gets initialized below
    init?(coder: NSCoder, personDetails: String) {
      self.personDetails = personDetails
      super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var personLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        personLabel.text = personDetails
    }
}
```

The next step is to select the ViewController's top part in the storyboard so you can see the three icons.

[image: Select ViewController from which you pass data]

Following that, you have to select the Segue which goes out from the second UINavigationController to your destination ViewController here PersonViewController and drag back from the segue to the first yellow icon of the ViewController you want to send information from like on the screenshot below. Xcode will automatically recognize the IBSegueAction's name which you created in code.

[image: StoryBoard]

That's it.

You should get a result like this once you tap any of the cells in the first View Controller

[image: Sample]

Here is the sample project [GitHub](https://github.com/verebes1/PassingData)

I also found more information about IBSegueAction [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/better-storyboards-with-xcode-11/)

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is exactly what I DON'T want to do - this is the pre-iOS 13 way of doing it. Using `IBSegueActions` (a new feature of iOS 13) allows you to initialise view controllers without optionals

Comment: @AshleyMills got it fixed using IBSegueAction check the repo I update my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you (again), but please read the question again. I know how to use an `IBSegueAction` when passing data to a regular view controller. I know how to push a view controller on to a nav stack. What I want to know how is how to do it when initialising a view controller _contained in a modal `UINavigationController`_

Comment: I don't understand why do you need two UINavigationControllers. As the first one should handle the other ViewController as well. Do you have a minimal example which I could play around with?

Comment: Have you ever written an app where you present a modal view controller contained in a navigation controller? This is a very common use case - think of a settings view controller for example. Note - I'm NOT pushing it on to the nav stack. I'm presenting it modally

Comment: I have not. I think I found the problem. Have a look at the github repo and try the project. I believe that the Segue on your StoryBoard should be connected to the PersonViewController not to the NavigationController. this way you can pass data as you wanted and it shows modally

Comment: OK, we're getting closer! So the problem here is that even though the `PersonViewController` is contained within a `UINavigationController` in the storyboard, because the destination of the segue is the `PersonViewController` when it's actually displayed it's not inside the nav controller. Try pointing the segue at the nav controller and you'll see the difference (it has a nav bar at the top, for a start)

Comment: Have you checked the github example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201609/discussion-between-ashley-mills-and-ad-progress).

Comment: @AshleyMills check my latest GitHub Commit. The result is there with a bit of hack

Comment: @AshleyMills check my latest commit on my GitHub I have solved the problem. Will fully update the answer today. The main thing is the screenshot which shows how You need to create your IBSegueAction to achieve the result you want.

Comment: That's it… you've got it! That's exactly the answer I was hoping for. Thank you very much. Update your answer to match the screenshot and I'll accept and award you the bounty.

Comment: @AshleyMills I have updated the answer as well as the code on my GitHub. Hopefully this will be helpful for others as well.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again. The key that I was missing was to connect the `rootViewController`segue to the `IBSegueAction`

Comment: I figured out what's going on… it's all about the responder chain. See my note at the top of the question.

Comment: It almost works.... if the final ViewController is in a separate storyboard, linked via a storyboard reference.... then it again, it tries to instantiate using the wrong init. 

Comment: It's possible by using an intermediary view controller as the initial view controller of your other storyboard. Then that intermediary view controller has an embed segue to the navigation controller... it's nasty, but less nasty than having optionals, and allows you to use the IBSegueAction across storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but managed to get it working. Instead of setting your segue action selector on your Show Detail segue, set it on Navigation Controller's Relationship Segue, as in the following screenshot:

[image: right clicking navigation controller's relationship segue]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the best way.

But I **don't want to create**

1. Custom Navigation Class
2. Initializer in the Target ViewController

---

**Storyboard**

[image]

---

**Segue**

```
// MARK: - Segue
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension DrawingViewController {

    @IBSegueAction private func prepareImagePickerSegue(coder: NSCoder, sender: Any?, segueIdentifier: String?) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let navigationController = UINavigationController(coder: coder),
           let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "ImagePicker", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImagePickerViewController") as? ImagePickerViewController else { return nil }


        // Prepare the target viewController
        viewController.delegate = self


        // Set navigation
        navigationController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)

        return navigationController
     }
}
```